# No volume in dispart

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, diskpart

I plugged Seagate 1 TB external hard disk into my computer and used ***Diskpart*** to check the detail information of disk. I can correctly select the USB drive. However, when I type `detail disk` in Diskpart, I receive an error message: **there are no volumes**. Why and how to fix this error?
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjOU5.jpg) 
**Hint:** Hard disk does not show up anywhere except in Device Manager. 
**Edit:** The issue started after I plugged disk into my android phone then back into pc.It does not appear in [file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAVsb.png)  or in [disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehYpj.png).Ony it appears in [Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKLvT.png)

Comment: Please don't delete then repost the same question.

Comment: @Tetsujin NO..my disk is not dead

Comment: why do you think your disk is not dead? it doesn't show anywhere, the device in device manager is just the USB disk controller where the disk is connected and as it does not show up in disk management - it means that it is not recognised. the only way to know is to remove the disk from the external enclosure and connect it to a correct controller - it might be that the controller in the enclosure is fried on the disk side as it is seen in devmgr. check the system event log - you might find more information there.